# Convert SQL query to Rails ActiveRecord query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `sql` query with multiple left joins that works fine:

```
query = <<-eos
      select date(t.completed_at) completed_date, s.id district, assignee_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, count(t.id) completed_tasks
      from tasks t
      left join tickets k on k.id = t.ticket_id
      left join installations i on i.id = k.installation_id
      left join administrative_areas a on i.ward_id = a.id
      left join service_areas s on s.id = a.service_district_id
      left join users u on u.id = t.assignee_id
      where 1 = 1
      and s.id = '#{district_id}'
      and t.status = '#{status}'
      and t.kind = 1
      and t.completed_at >= '#{days_ago.days.ago.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}'
      and t.completed_at <= '#{days_until.days.ago.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}'
      group by date(t.completed_at), s.id, s.name, u.first_name, u.last_name, t.assignee_id
      eos
```

I got this value after mapping: `[{:completed_date=>"2015-07-11", :district=>"1339", :assignee_id=>"215371", :assignee_name=>nil, :first_name=>"John_9", :last_name=>"Ant", :completed_tasks=>"1"}]` for the `sql` query.

But I want to stop using the `sql` query and switch to `ActiveRecord` query and I have it converted to `ActiveRecord` like this:

```
Task.joins("LEFT JOIN tickets k ON k.id = tasks.ticket_id").
        joins("LEFT JOIN installations i ON i.id = k.installation_id").
        joins("LEFT JOIN administrative_areas a ON i.ward_id = a.id").
        joins("LEFT JOIN service_areas s ON s.id = a.service_district_id").
        joins("LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = tasks.assignee_id").
        where(["s.id = ? and tasks.status = ? and tasks.kind = ? and tasks.completed_at >= ? and tasks.completed_at <= ?", 26, "#{status}", 1, "#{days_ago.days.ago.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}", "#{days_until.days.ago.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}"]).
        select('date(tasks.completed_at) as completed_date, s.id as district, assignee_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, count(tasks.id) as completed_tasks').
        group("date(tasks.completed_at), s.id, s.name, u.first_name, u.last_name, tasks.assignee_id")
```

But the problem I have here is trying to do a `select` from multiple columns in different tables, the only value that the `ActiveRecord` query returns belong to the task table alone. I don't know what am doing wrong, maybe it's the `left joins` or the `select`

```
[#<Task status: 1, assignee_id: 215356, kind: 1>]
```

Please, how do I convert the above `sql` query to `ActiveRecord` query and get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/) the first result is always terrible, but try to configure associations in second tab. And please try to avoid constructions like this:

```
where("params.id = #{param[:id]}")
```

it is unsecured (sql injection)!

Comment: Thanks for your help, that didn't work for me. `Task.joins(:tickets, installations: :administrative_areas ...)` is exactly what I want to convert the query to.

Comment: Try to use .to_sql on your ActiveRecord query representation and compare with the old SQL statement...